# Better codes for ring-finding program in python

Tags: python, graph-theory

I wrote a ring detection program in a very stupid way. Can anyone help to improve it? The following code is to find all 5-member rings. I need a general function which is able to find N-member rings, where N is typically less than 10. Thanks a million!

In my problem, I have about 2000 points. Each point connected to several other points, these connected points are stored in `neighbor_list`. And the `point[i].neighbor_list()` return a list of the neighbors of point[i]. The idea in the following code is starting from one point, traverse its neighbor list and it's neighbor's neighbor list, and so on, to find the routes/cycles/rings to go back to the original point. The central part of my code is the following, which finds only rings formed by 5 points. I need a general code to find all N-member rings. Please leave a comment if anything is not clear.

```
for r0 in range(2000): #ring member 0
    rin.append(r0)
    for r1 in point[r0].neighbor_list():
        rin.append(r1) #ring member 1 
        for r2 in point[r1].neighbor_list():
            if r2 == r0: continue # to avoid the case of a-b-a ...
            else: rin.append(r2)
            for r3 in point[r2].neighbor_list():
                if r3 == r1: continue
                else: rin.append(r3)
                for r4 in point[r3].neighbor_list():
                    if r4 == r2: continue
                    else: rin.append(r4)
                    for r5 in point[r4].neighbor_list():
                        if r5 == r0: 
                            rin.append(r5)
                            rings.append(list(rin)) # find a ring, save it
                            rin.pop()
                        else: continue  
                    rin.pop()
                rin.pop()
            rin.pop()
        rin.pop()
    rin.pop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'ring'?

Comment: And what are these objects such that `neighbor_list()` works? (and what does it return despite the obvious!)

Comment: to That1Guy and Jon Clements: Thanks for the response. I am sorry for the confusing message. Each point connected to several points, these connected points are stored in its neighbor_list. And the point[i].neighbor_list() return a list of these neighbors. So the idea is starting from one point, traverse its neighbor list and it's neighbor's neighbor list, see if there is a route go back to the original point. The route is defined as a ring. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: @That1Guy: Thanks for the response. Please see above my explanation.

Comment: @Jon Clements: Thanks for the response. Please see above my explanation

Comment: I have added "Graph theory" tag. Your problem involve a graph. You may want to explore this subject as it is very interesting and useful.

Comment: I edited my question, hope it's more clear now, although I believe the original question is clear enough with the code itself. Hope Slater Tyranus, glts, Viktor Kerkez, and George Stocker can release their hold soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find cycles of size N in an undirected graph.

You may find all cycles and then select the ones with right size. See this answer.
[Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need some time to learn the "breadth first search" to see if it works for me.

Comment: The first link I put was not correct, it was for detecting one cycle. I quickly edited it to "all cycles" but not quickly enough. You are lucky, there is even an answer python code with this question. (I didn't test it)

Comment: Thanks again. The python code in the link doesn't seem work for my problem. I have 2000 points and about 8000 edges, which might make it impossible to find all cycles. I tried to give a break, "if len(path) > 10: break", to the loop "for edge in graph:", that did not seem to help either. I never find any cycle by that code, while my code above take 1 second to find all 5-points cycles.