# List all negative cycles in directed graph

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

For a directed graph G(V,E) where it has negative weights, I searched some similar topics and it seems Bellmanford can detect negative cycles. But it stops once negative cycles found, so how can we list all negative cycles in this case?

Given thoughts on Eric Lippert's suggestion, I tried removing negative cycles once found from graph, but I feel this is not correct, why? because the graph changes after cycles are removed and there could be extra non-negative cycles in old graph but not gonna be found in new graph. 
Can someone please help clear my mind on this issue?

this can be implemented in either java or c# (i prefer c# though)

thanks

Comment: Looks like you don't need `java` tag..

Comment: sorry, i was changing it, but you were quicker..

Comment: Find a negative cycle. Remove it. Now search again. Repeat until you can no longer find a negative cycle. Now you've counted the negative cycles.

Comment: but that only track the count, right? i need the full path though

Comment: what exactly is a negative cycle?

Comment: a cycle whose edges sum to a negative value in a directed graph

Comment: @EricLippert An edge can participate in more than one cycle. For example, there are O(n^2) edges in the complete graph on *n* vertices, but an [exponential number of cycles](http://oeis.org/A002807).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you certainly can't find them efficiently: consider the complete graph on `n` vertices with a weight of negative -1 on each edge. There are [an exponential number of negative-weight cycles in this graph](http://oeis.org/A002807) and as such it'd take exponential time to just write them all down!

If that doesn't deter you though, your best bet is to apply any old cycle finding algorithm, such as the ones in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs) to find all cycles, and then just throw out those cycles with non-negative weight.

Comment: my understanding is that it will be exponential number if we try to find every single cycle in a graph, but if we point out the origin node, then the number of cycles will be limited, is that right?

Comment: Not significantly. Suppose you have a complete graph and you pick a specific node to be the origin. Consider the length `n` cycles passing through this node: there are obviously `(n-1)!` length `n-1` simple paths going out of this node, and we can just add the edge between where ever a path ends and the origin to form a cycle. So there are `(n-1)!` cycles of size `n` through the origin, which is an exponential quantity.

Comment: The only ways I can think of to beat the combinatorial explosion are to either consider a very restricted set of cycles (say all those of less than a fixed length), or to restrict yourself to almost-treelike graphs. Edit: What do you actually want the list of all negative-weight cycles for? If you can give some context, there might be a shortcut.