# I got points on a map.Getting all independent inner polygons that are formed?

Tags: c#, google-maps

I got points on a map and lines connecting those points.

How do I get all independent inner polygons that are formed?

The linked picture describes the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRWQX.jpg

I'm supposing I need a tree search algorithm that enumerates all the points and connecting lines in a tree structure and then searches for cycles but this job is kinda over my head.

In a perfect world the example would be in C#.)

---

I found:

[Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs)

but it does not mark independent polygons. It finds all possible polygons even overlapping ones.

---

I'm using google maps. The use case is: I detect clicks on map and draw points. I detect click on points and then get lines between points. Now I need to automaticaly generate polygons from the lines and points. Sure I can draw polygons. I just dont know which ones (what coordinates - or rather: what points to choose for a polygon)

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/144442/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have no experience in graphics and how to actually colour a polygon once you've found it, but assuming:

1. You have the polygons themselves.
2. They do not patialy overlap or any other weird behaviour.

Then the colouring pseudo code could go something like this:

```
while listOfPolygons is not empty
    temp <- find smallest polygon in listOfPolygons 
    colour temp
    remove from listOfPolygons all polygons containing temp
    remove temp from listOfPolygons
```

Notice that the part about finding the containing polygons might be tricky.

Edit:

Checking if polygon A is in polygon B can be done by checking if any corner (vertex?) of A is located inside B.

Comment: I think I got the code for finding all polygons (the link in the update). Also I think this is the solution. I will leave the question open for a bit. Thanks :)

They only overlap in the sense that smaller polygons are part of larger ones.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm wondering will this work if two polygons are side by side and share a vertex. I dont think so.

Comment: Two polygons with a common edge (yellow and green in your picture) do not have any corners that are located IN the other...