# how to improve performance of finding all cycles in undirected graphs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph

I have reference the question [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs) . and write a javascript version, but I got the performance problem, I run on chrome, it took about 8 seconds, too a long time,  for only 16 vertices and 33 edges on my undirected graphs. this is codes:

```js
<script>
    var graph = [[37,36], [37,168], [37,85], [37,2264], [37,3203], [36,85], [36,536], [36,5097], [85,168], [85,654], [85,755], [85,3607], [85,4021], [85,5097], [168,755], [536,4021], [536,5097], [536,5464], [536,6533], [654,3607], [654,4021], [654,5564], [654,6533], [755,2357], [755,3203], [755,3607], [2264,2357], [2264,3203], [2357,3203], [4021,5097], [5464,5564], [5464,6533], [5564,6533]];
    var cycles = [];

    function findAllCycles() {
        var i, j, len;

        var st1 = new Date().getTime();

        for (i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            var edge = graph[i];
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                findNewCycles( [edge[j]] );
            }
        }

        var st2 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log("time: " + (st2-st1));
    };

    function findNewCycles(path) {
        var startNode = path[0],
            nextNode;

        // visit each edge and each node of each edge
        for (var i = 0; i < graph.length; i++) {
            var edge = graph[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                var node = edge[j];
                if (node === startNode) //  edge refers to our current node
                {
                    nextNode = edge[(j + 1) % 2];
                    if ( !visited(nextNode, path) ) { //  neighbor node not on path yet
                        //  explore extended path
                        findNewCycles( [nextNode].concat(path), graph, cycles );
                    }
                    else if ( (path.length > 2) && (nextNode === path[path.length - 1]) ) { //  cycle found
                        //var p = normalize(path);
                        //var inv = invert(p);
                        if ( isNew(path, cycles) ) {
                            cycles.push(path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // check if vertex n is contained in path
    function visited(node, path) {
        return (path.indexOf(node) !== -1);
    }

    function isNew(path, cycles) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cycles.length; i++) {
            if ( equal(path, cycles[i]) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    function equal(path1, path2) {
        if (path1.length !== path2.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < path1.length; i++) {
            var node1 = path1[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < path2.length; j++) {
                var node2 = path2[j];
                if (node1 === node2) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (j === path2.length) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    findAllCycles();
    console.log(cycles);
</script>
```

how can I improve the performance.

Comment: Well, you should start by using a fast node<->edge lookup structure, instead of iterating over the edge set.

Comment: minor suggestions: equal() function seems bloated... can't you just loop over path1 and check path1[i] == path2[i]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try things differently.

You could calculate for each node it's depths. If you ever come to a node that already has a depth, then you have a cycles.

This algorithm would be in O(n) where n is the number of node. It should be much faster.

If you don't care about depth you could just "tag" the node.

Comment: An `O(n)` algorithm can hardly be correct, as the result size is larger than `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not the implementation of your algorithm. This graph is deceptively complicated, apparently containing a total of 3930 cycles! Including 39 chordless cycles plus 3891 cycles with chords (which include smaller cycles inside).

[image]

This is similar to the "how many squares" problem, it can be surprising how quickly it adds up.

[image]

You may be able to optimize significantly if you are only interested in chordless cycles.

(Side note: the equals function seems overly complicated, but this is presumably doesn't significantly affect performance)

```
function pathIsEqual(path1, path2) {

    if (path1.length !== path2.length) {
        return false
    }

    for(var i = path1.length; i--;) {
        if(path1[i] !== path2[i]){
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```