# How to get all Cycles from a geotools graph?

Tags: graph, path, cycle, geotools

Does anyone know how to get all existing cycles in a geotools graph? The CycleDetector object that exists merely identifies if there are any cirlces in the graph, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a little vague.  Are you modeling your graphs as directed or undirected graphs?  Also, if you want a handle on 'all' cycles, you likely need a notion of 'minimal' cycles.  (Otherwise, one could say that A->B->C->A, A->B->C->A->B->C->A, and A->B->C->A->B->C->A->B->C->A are all cycles in the graph.)

As a helpful piece of code, I'd recommend checking out the [GraphPartitioner](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/extension/graph/src/main/java/org/geotools/graph/util/graph/GraphPartitioner.java).  If your graph consists of disjoint components, this class will break the larger graph into disjoint pieces.

For each of those pieces, you could run the CycleDetector (or the Directed version [DirectedCycleDetector](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/extension/graph/src/main/java/org/geotools/graph/util/graph/DirectedCycleDetector.java)) to see if there is any work to be done on the connected sub-graph.

Looks like this question is also relevant: [Finding all cycles in undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The truth is I was a little vague about my problem indeed. I know about the cycle detector but I was thinking something like the triangle in delauny triangulation. Like geting objects for minimum closed paths from a graph. Nevertheless, your answer helped my understand what GraphPartitioner does. I hadn't noticed that in order to work the graph should have disjoint components and I was struggling in vain all this time! So thanks!