# Develop an algorithm running time O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, graph, runtime

Can you give me an hint how to develop an algorithm as this task? Everytime if I am reading something like this I don't know how to develop with using the run time. Thanks!

Give an algorithm that determines whether or not a given undirected graph
G = (V;E) contains a cycle. Your algorithm should run in O(|V|) time, independent of |E|.

Comment: Can you find what you are searching in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs ?

Comment: Thanks its a helpful content. But I am interested into the way to solve such a problem or in general O(nlogn). How can I create an algorithm with this runtime? Because I don't know how to solve this problem. I mean how to work with runtime and develop the code which cover this.

Comment: For a normal (no multi-edge) connected undirected graph, if number of edges is greater than number of vertices-1, [ e > v-1] then there will be a cycle.

Comment: I doubt if there is any algorithm that should run in O(|V|) unless you can come up with a new technique. The DFS and BFS techniques for detecting cycle both has time complexity is O(V+E).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there aren't algorithms for that problem working with only |V|, obviously, you can conclude some cases for example if |E| >= |V| and every edge is different(different pair) there will be a cycle, but it's not necessary. You can consider also more cases for example when |V| <= 2 or |E| <= 2.