# Determine polygon coordinates from custom txt map

Tags: python, r, computational-geometry

I have a `.txt` file that looks like this

```
+----------+--------+------------------+
|          |         \                 |
|          |          \                |
|          |           \               |
|          |            +------+-------+
|          |                   |       |
|          |                   |       |
+----------+-------------------+-------+
```

How can I identify these polygons?

For this example, I expect to identify 4 polygons.

I can read the lines and identify, for example, the coordinates (row, col) for every vertice ("+"), but I'm not sure how to get the edges coordinates. My main goal here is to have a set of points describing every polygons' bounding regions.

How can I do this in R or Python?

Comment: step 1: parse the txt file to find all the graph vertices (+) and all the edges (connecting lines between vertices).  step 2: use a graph package (e.g. R `igraph`) and load the vertices and edges into the graph model.  step 3: [find all minimal circuits in the undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367801/finding-all-cycles-in-undirected-graphs)

Comment: Sure, but how does one go about step1? That is the main issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not claiming this is very efficient, but it's at least one way to tackle the problem in R. First, here's how i've read in the data.

```
raw <- r"(
+----------+--------+------------------+
|          |         \                 |
|          |          \                |
|          |           \               |
|          |            +------+-------+
|          |                   |       |
|          |                   |       |
+----------+-------------------+-------+
)"

data <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(readLines(textConnection(raw)), ""))
```

This creates an array `data` that has the same number of rows and columns as the input with all of the characters of the input.

The basic idea is that I try to fill each of the "empty" areas in the region and keep track of all the corners that we meet during the fill. So first, a helper function to get the rows/columns around a given cell

```
allnei <- expand.grid(-1:1, -1:1)
allnei <- allnei[allnei[,1] !=0 | allnei[,2] !=0, ]
get_neighbors <- function(point, data) {
  cand <- t(c(point) +t(allnei))
  cand[
    cand[,1]>=1 & cand[,1]<=nrow(data) & 
    cand[,2]>=1 & cand[,2]<=ncol(data), 
    TRUE
  ]
}
```

and then most of the work happens on the `fill` function

```
fill <- function(point, data, corners=matrix(nrow=0, ncol=2), fill_with="1") {
  if (!is.matrix(point)) {
    point <- matrix(point, ncol=2)
  }
  cand <- get_neighbors(point, data)
  data[point] <- fill_with
  corner_cand <- which(data[cand] == "+")
  if (length(corner_cand)) {
    corners <- unique(rbind(corners, cand[corner_cand, ]))  
  }
  empty_cand <- which(data[cand] == " "  & (cand[,1]==point[,1] | cand[,2]==point[,2]))
  if (length(empty_cand)>0) {
    for(i in empty_cand) {
      result <- fill(cand[i,], data, corners, fill_with)
      data <- result$data
      corners <- unique(rbind(corners, result$corners))
    }
  }
  list(data=data, corners=corners)
}
```

So starting with an "empty" cell, we look for adjacent cells and mark them as the same region. We do this recursively until we run out of adjacent empty cells.

Now we need a wrapper that will keep doing this until there are no empty regions.

```
find_regions <- function(data) {
  regions <- list()
  reg <- 1
  empty <- which(data==" ", arr.ind=TRUE)
  while(nrow(empty)>0) {
    empty <- empty[1,]
    results <- fill(empty, data, fill_with=reg)    
    regions <- c(regions, list(results$corners))
    data <- results$data
    reg <- reg+1
    empty <- which(data==" ", arr.ind=TRUE)
  }
  list(data=data, regions=regions)
}
result <- find_regions(data)
result$regions
```

Which gives the output

```
[1]]
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    8    1
[3,]    8   12
[4,]    1   12

[[2]]
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    1   12
[2,]    8   12
[3,]    1   21
[4,]    5   25
[5,]    5   32
[6,]    8   32

[[3]]
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    5   25
[2,]    5   32
[3,]    5   40
[4,]    1   40

[[4]]
     Var1 Var2
[1,]    5   32
[2,]    8   32
[3,]    5   40
[4,]    8   40
```

where are all the row/column positions for the vertices of the polygons. And we can see the regions with

```
cat(paste(apply(result$data, 1, paste, collapse=""), collapse="\n"))
# +----------+--------+------------------+
# |1111111111|222222222\33333333333333333|
# |1111111111|2222222222\3333333333333333|
# |1111111111|22222222222\333333333333333|
# |1111111111|222222222222+------+-------+
# |1111111111|2222222222222222222|4444444|
# |1111111111|2222222222222222222|4444444|
# +----------+-------------------+-------+
```

I also considered extracting the list of connected corners. This method basically looks for all the corners, looks in the directions where a "wall" or connector is present and then finds the first corner in that direction. We then keep track of all the discovered pairs. So first, here's a helper function to find "connected" corners

```
find_hit <- function(corner, corners, rvec, cvec) {
  best <- NA
  best_dist <- Inf
  for(i in 1:nrow(corners)) {
    rdist <- corners[i, 1] - corner[,1]
    cdist <- corners[i, 2] - corner[,2]
    if(sign(rdist) == sign(rvec) & sign(cdist) == sign(cvec) & 
      ((rvec ==0 | cvec== 0) | (rdist%/%rvec ==cdist %/%cvec))) {
      dist <- rdist + cdist
      if (dist < best_dist) {
        best_dist <- dist
        best <- i
      }
    }
  }
  best
}
```

The idea is that given a point and a list of candidate points, we look along a particular "vector" to see of there is a point at the end of that direction and return the first hit. We also have a number helper to make sure the points we are looking at are "in bounds"

```
in_bounds <- (function(data) {
  function(r, c) {
    r > 0 & r <= nrow(data) & c > 0 & c <= ncol(data)
  }
})(data)
```

Now we find all the corners and loop through them to find the connections

```
corners <- which(data=="+", arr.ind = TRUE)
edges <- list()
for (i in 1:(nrow(corners)-1)) {
  corner <- corners[i, , drop=FALSE]
  rest <- corners[-(1:i), , drop=FALSE]
  r <- corner[, 1]
  c <- corner[, 2]
  for (dr in c(-1, 0, 1)) {
    for (dc in c(-1, 0, 1)) {
      if (in_bounds(r+dr, c+dc) & (dr != 0| dc != 0) && data[r+dr, c+dc]!=" ") {
        hit <- find_hit(corner, rest, dr, dc)
        if (!is.na(hit)) {
          edges <- c(edges, list(c(i, i+hit)))
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
edges
```

So `edges` is a list telling which corners are connected. We can turn this into an igraph object with

```
library(igraph)
dd <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, edges))
dd[] <- lapply(dd, as.character)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dd, directed = FALSE)
vnames <- as.character(1:nrow(corners))
V(g)[vnames]$row <- corners[,1]
V(g)[vnames]$col <- corners[,2]
plot(g)
```

[image: connected corner graph]

And then you can get the row/column information out with

```
as.data.frame(vertex_attr(g))
```

And to put them in the right shape, you can set the `x` and `y` attributes (here I flip the y direction since (0,0) is lower left when plotting but top left in the matrix)

```
V(g)[vnames]$y <- -corners[,1]
V(g)[vnames]$x <- corners[,2]

plot(g)
```

[image: points in map order]

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

different way of searching the text string for the graph elements than @MrFlick.  I'm only showing horizontal edge search below.  you'll need to add vertical and diagonal searches.

```
string= "+----------+--------+------------------+
|          |         \                 |
|          |          \                |
|          |           \               |
|          |            +------+-------+
|          |                   |       |
|          |                   |       |
+----------+-------------------+-------+
"

#convert string to ascii numeric matrix
graph_matrix = as.matrix(do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(string,"\n")[[1]],utf8ToInt) ))

#scan for horizontal lines
on_line=F
edges= data.frame()
for (row in 1:dim(graph_matrix)[1]) {
  for (col in 1:dim(graph_matrix)[2]) {
    if (graph_matrix[row,col]==45&on_line==F) {
      on_line=T
      edge = c(col-1,row)
    } else if (graph_matrix[row,col]!=45&on_line==T)  {
      on_line=F
      edge = c(edge,col,row)
      edges = rbind(edges,edge)
    }
  }
}
colnames(edges) = c("x1","y1","x2","y2")
edges

#unique vertices
non_unique = mapply(c,edges[,1:2],edges[,3:4])
unique_verts = non_unique[!duplicated(non_unique),]
unique_verts
```